# Adobe Flex - show custom tooltip on button click

Tags: apache-flex, custom-controls, tooltip

I am trying to make a custom Flex tooltip a la [this tutorial](http://blog.comtaste.com/2009/05/how_to_create_a_custom_tooltip_1.html).  It's basically just a bunch of labels showing a colour legend.  This all works fine and well when the tooltip shows from the button event `toolTipCreate`:

```
<mx:Button label="ToolTip example" toolTip=" "
  toolTipCreate="toolTipCreateHandler(event)" />
```

However, I want to show the tooltip when the button is clicked and not wait for the actual tooltip delay.  (In this sense, I'm not even sure if the terminology "tooltip" even applies anymore, but that's for another time).  I call the same handler with an instantiated ToolTipEvent being passed as the argument:

```
<mx:Button label="ToolTip example" toolTip=" "
  click="toolTipCreateHandler(new ToolTipEvent(ToolTipEvent.CREATE, false, false, instanceOfMyCustomToolTip))" />
```

However, this doesn't work, and it's driving me up the wall trying to figure out how to do this.  This doesn't seem like such an uncommon thing to do, but every example I find on the internet uses the actual tooltip delay instead of a button click.  Any help would be appreciated.

P.S. - I want to do it as a tooltip specifically so I can try to get the little "balloon tail" [as shown here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf60d65-7ff6.html).

**EDIT**: I have also tried `ToolTipManager.createToolTip` in the click event of the button, but this doesn't work either.

```
<mx:Button id="ttt" label="Tooltip test"
  click="ToolTipManager.createToolTip(' ',75,75,'errorTipBelow',instanceOfMyCustomToolTip)"/>
```

Comment: Refer this link might be help full http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=tooltips_4.html

Comment: @rajesh.adhi:  I've already looked at that page a million times, and none of those examples show a custom tooltip based on a button click.

Comment: Costume means, okay you are able to show the tool tip but you want to give a costume skin for that right ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After much research, this is impossible in its current form.  Here is what *should* work:

```
<mx:Button id="ttt" label="Tooltip test"
  click="createTooltip()"/>

private function createTooltip():void {
  ToolTipManager.toolTipClass = MyCustomToolTip;
  ToolTipManager.createToolTip('any text here');
}
```

At this point, the ToolTipManager **should** create a new tooltip using the class specified in `ToolTipManager.toolTipClass`.  However, due to a yet-unresolved bug in the Adobe Flex SDK, `ToolTipManager.createToolTip` ignores this class and always uses the default class `ToolTip`.

So nothing short of a monkey patch will get this to work correctly.  Found info on this bug (and corresponding patch) [in this blog post](http://benclinkinbeard.com/2008/07/simple-monkey-patch-to-fix-tooltipmanagertooltipclass/index.html).  The post talks about Flex 3, but this bug is still unresolved as of Flex 4.5.1.

Comment: Were you ever able to figure this out? I'm using 4.15 and there's no `ToolTipManager.showToolTip(component)` method. You'd think there would be.

Comment: No, I never figured it out, but I do not use Flex any more.